# Barbell rubbing rough over upper crotch when doing Reeves Shrug

Tags: shoulders, barbell

Trying to do the exercise as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/0s7DP9QOwQI?si=kyOTO-OMS9fDeYWB). There is a very annoying part where when I'm trying to pull it up, it rubs quite hard against my crotch leading to an embarrasing moments.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your form is a bit off? have you tried leaning a bit forward, or using a shorter barbell? Possibly less weight until you can control it better? Ultimately, choose a different shrug variation (dumbbells, for example)

Comment: @Luciano - Longer barbell. You want to increase the distance, a shorter barbell would let it hang even lower.

Answer (score -1):

Easy hack: For the inner weights, ones you actually hold, use ones with smaller radius. After that keep an even smaller radius weight after and then stack the heavier weights.